# How Do I change extension of php file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change the extension of php file.For example the file home.php is called in browser it should be shows like home.html.
I can done it in codeigniter by using **suffix** variable in config file.But how can i achieve it in core php? I think it can be done through .htaccess file or may be from other way but how to do?please let me know.

i try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

by using above code i try to but it is was not changed? or if there any other way to do it please let me know.

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want that the whenver the php file is called on browser than it must show home.html insted of home.php.

Comment: I understand your question. I just don't understand why you would want to do that.

Comment: @BartFriederichs ,i just want to make a practice to change the url

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

It will redirect any request to a html file (that does not exists phisicaly) to a php file.

Comment: what error do you get ? what else do you got in your htaccess file ?

Comment: i just paste your code in htaccess file and call my php file in browser,but it still shows home.php

Comment: did you call home.php or home.html

Comment: Then you didn't read what I wrote, I said that if you try to access index.html, it will redirect the request to index.html (that what most of the time people want) , why do you want to request index.php and be redirected to index.html (while the true file is index.php) ?

Comment: ,i think there is some misunderstanding.look i have a site developed in core php.its all url shows like that:-www.example.com/home.php and i want to show it as www.example.com/home.html. so if from any other html page there is a link of my site ,should be shown as in .html extension.if still any doubt feel free for ask. thanks

Comment: If you want to change your links, you will have to go to all pages of your site and change all the links to .html , then you can use the rules I gave you to redirect .html to .php, htacces does not change the links in your pages, it just redirect requests.

Comment: so if i am using php code and the file name turn to .html.so is affected the functionalists of php?

Comment: the php code will no longer be executed, you need to change the links in the files but don't change the files extentions, and just use the rule I wrote to redirect any request to an html file to a php file internaly (the user will still see in the url file.html, but the server will execute file.php instead)

Comment: You are welcome, sorry that this is not what you were expecting